# как стилизовать ссылку страницы на которой я сейчас нахожусь

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
  <ul class="menu_serv">
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Вывожу ссылки страныц, но не знаю как стилизовать ссылку страницы на которой я сейчас нахожусь. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_queried_object_id()
```

это ID текущего поста (или страницы), на которой вы находитесь. Соответственно, Вам необходимо выполнить проверку ID объекта, который вы хотите стилизовать, с данным.